# where to find apoc.conf in neo4j sandbox

Tags: python, json, neo4j

using neo4j for first time
running neo4j on broweser as my neo4j desktop version is not working

TRYING TO LOAD JSON INTO IT BUT IT SAYS
`` Failed to invoke procedure `apoc.load.json`: Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Import from files not enabled, please set apoc.import.file.enabled=true in your apoc.conf ``

MY COMMAND

```
call apoc.load.json("///apoc.json") yield value
```

im unable any such file in browser all videos or answer are about neo4j desktop version where this file is present in settings

:=NEO4J is soooo confusing (for me )

Answer (score 1):

No worries Robin, we are here to help. Read this website if you want the full details: https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/import/load-json/

> 1. Go find your neo4j home directory and under 'conf' folder you will find a file:  neo4j.conf.
>    Yes! it is the same apoc.conf mentioned in the
>    error message.
>    Confusion is solved :D
> 2. Copy and paste this configuration setting in neo4j.conf (or apoc.conf)
>    apoc.import.file.enabled=true
> 3. Lastly go to 'import' folder then save your json file: apoc.json and stop/start your neo4j server. Scripts are found at /bin directory

```
CALL apoc.load.json("file:///apoc.json")
YIELD value
RETURN value;
```

Comment: will this work for neo4j browser version ? bcoz my desktop version doesnt work

Comment: yes, I just tested on my neo4j browser and it works. If you have an issue, send me your script and error(s).

Comment: apoc.conf = neo4j.conf is something I overlooked in the first place